# How to make my div remain closed even after refreshing

Tags: javascript, php

I am new to php,i want to make my div to be closed even after refreshing.

my HTML code:

```
<div id="help_box" class="notification-page notification-info has-close-button">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="closehelp" title="Hide help" class="help-close float_right"></a>
div content
</div>
```

my JS code

```
$('#closehelp').click(function(){
  $('#help_box').animate({ height:"hide", opacity:"hide", marginBottom:"-25px" },"slow");
});
```

On clicking close button my div hide,and if i refresh the page div appears.

How to hide it even if i refresh?? I searched for a long time but i cant progress.

Comment: You could use a cookie to store the actual div's state (hidden or not), read that cookie with PHP and add a class to the `help_box` to flag it as closed.

Comment: give the div a style of `display:none`

Comment: If you're trying to always have the div hidden on page load, you'll need to add `display: none` to you css. If you're trying to save the user's action, whether they hid the div or not, then you'll need to look into sessions/cookies.

Comment: Use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)

Comment: when you refresh the page it load the css and js from very starting point so by using js and css you can't do it.. you have to use the cookies or localStorage..

Answer (score 4):

You have to use cookies to keep hide your div even after refreshing after clicking on close button.

When you click on close button,set a cookie with a expiry time(as long you do not want to show the div),as following

```
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays)
{
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

$('#closehelp').click(function(){
$('#help_box').animate({ height:"hide", opacity:"hide", marginBottom:"-25px" },"slow");
setCookie('closediv',1,1);
});
```

//cookie will expire after one day

and then read the cookie in php.If cookie is available then keep the display:none of the div.

```
<?php $cookie=$_COOKIE['closediv'];?>
<div id="help_box" class="notification-page notification-info has-close-button" <?php if($cookie):?> style="display:none" <?php endif;?>>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="closehelp" title="Hide help" class="help-close float_right"></a>
div content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use something like this==>

`jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#help_box').toggle();
})`

Comment: How this will hide the div after refreshing?

Comment: Adding Javascript on load is overhead. You can simply type inline CSS : display:none for DIV.

Comment: @RahilWazir well... actually it will hide the div, because by default it isn't hidden, so the toggle function will do it. But it is impractical and inefficient... and probably not what the OP is looking for.